# Is this creature's proportional head size feasible?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design

I am irritatingly perfectionist and must know things to relax my anxiety.
So this creature here. From the top its head shape is salamander. Its mouth is large and strong and the cranium needs enough space for sentient brain and good fitting hats. It can switch to quadruped movement.
It is approximately 4 feet tall.

It will need to be able to not fall forward on its face from either stance. Not too top heavy. Would balance be an issue? I'd rather not give it a counter balance tail. Its body is roughly barrel shaped, so more thick support neck could fit. I'm unsure about the limb joint positioning, as I notice the quadruped shoulder and enlarged chest looks a bit weird on a biped (don't worry about the limb shape; those extra lines in the front are just for telling me its leg position as quadruped). The back legs are animal shaped and around the same length as its body plus halfway up the neck. Its hands and feet are like chicken feet.

Will these proportions work strength and balance wise? What might I need to change?

I hope you can see the images okay. I don't like to put down harder to erase lines until I'm very sure that's where they need to be.

[image: Side Merx]

[image: Front Merx]

I did a bit of change. The neck is a bit longer and thinner, if that makes it more realistic. The neck bones are positioned something like this. Im attempting to copy a chimp like head to neck connection for switching between biped and quadruped position.
[image: Merx neck]
Though now I'm concerned about if the brain case is too small in proportion or if it having the generally large head already makes up for it.

Am I allowed a side question? I need to know how stretchy a spine can be.

Potential head/neck fixes?
[image: Neck fixes?]

Maybe a slightly shorter head would make it more believable. His head is big and wide enough that it should make up for the shorter head height, for brain space. Hopefully the hat will still stay on okay. I could probably shorten it even more if I weren't worried about the hat falling off. (Hat base shown here) How do the spinous processes look? Do they look like they are enough and proper? I don't know much about those.
[image: shorter head + hat base + spinous processes]

Perhaps s neck.
[image: S neck]

Comment: I think that if you want us to evaluate the proportions of this creature you should throw in some numbers, not just adjectives.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica    Are the images not helpful?

Comment: Images , with no scale indicator, must be assumed to be on scale 1-1. so your being stands about 29 cm tall, and has a 5cm3 cranium. About the size of a small cat, but with a brain 1/7th as large

Comment: OK. 4 ft tall. so head is about human size, on a teenager body. That works. It allows for the *much* wider jaw. Eye placement is ok, the wide separation partially makes up for the immobile neck.

Comment: @PcMan why would the neck be immobile?

Comment: Tyrion Lannister says that the proportions of this beautiful creature are perfectly fine.

Comment: @AlexP who is that?

Comment: The neck is like that of a Walrus. But with space for only 1/4th as many vertebra. It will be a miracle if your creature could rotate, tilt or nod its head more than about 15 degrees to each side... There is just not enough distance between the shoulder and the bottom of the cranium, and the immense width of the neck further impedes movement. Effectively, your creature has the neck and head of a frog. Go and look up how mobile a frog's head is.

Comment: "I am irritatingly perfectionist and must know things to relax my anxiety." Me too!  (Hence my recent question whether or not I can justify my characters having naturally teal fur. Actually, hence *many* of my questions.)

Comment: I recommend trying to draw your quadrupedal stance

Answer (score 10):

I would say that it is perfectly feasible.

**1.** If we consider  [dwarfism in humans](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/796644621569232616/), it is frequently the case that the head appears proportionally larger than average with respect to the body. Yet such people can successfully take part in sports without overbalancing.

[image]

**2.** You mention salamanders and it is true that for example giant salamanders have large heads in proportion to their bodies. Of course a normal salamander does not stand upright but evolution could surely make this happen.

[image]

**3.** You would do well to consider the phenomenon of [neoteny](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/neoteny)

Young humans (who have relatively large heads) are capable of walking and running at an early age. If the species retained the childish shape longer then this would work perfectly well for someone 4ft tall.  By retaining the general body-shape of a two to five year old into adulthood but with larger muscle growth, and better co-ordination through experience, your creature could be perfectly well balanced.

[image]

**4.** Finally, here is a [video of 5-year-olds racing](https://youtu.be/_4K3gbYBtX0) 
[image: https://youtu.be/_4K3gbYBtX0]

Comment: I tend to not use juvenile creatures for reference images because the creature is incomplete and the proportions are temporary and not long term, thus the functionality of the shape does not need to be as refined, is how I see it.  I may be wrong though.                                                     Also does a long snout affect the balance in any way, for future reference?

Comment: I also tend to overestimate how much muscle and bone is needed to support things. If the flamingo were a fictional animal, I'd call it unrealistic.

Comment: Also what about how quadrupeds hold their heads out?

Comment: Look at almost any photo of a horse. They have very heavy heads but they can still hold them out.

Comment: If the head is held vertically above the spine then the force is applied downwards. This simply needs sufficient bone and muscle strength to keep it balanced whilst moving around.

Comment: Neoteny means that the creature *is* adult but it just retains juvenile characteristics. You might like to read about neoteny in humans. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoteny_in_humans

Comment: Or the size of a rabbit' head compared to its body.

Answer (score 5):

Your main problem is you want a variable stance but have drawn a perfectly upright neck. To work quadrupedally the neck articulate should be as horizontal as possible, for an up right stance it should be as vertical as possible. Animals like chimps and gorilla that do both use a compromise with something close to a 45 degree angle. Basically the angle of spine should match the angle of the neck to skull joint, if two drastically different spinal postures are uses you compromise between the two. A side effect of this is the neck posture is not optimal in either position, when upright it gets swung forward, so the whole head sits forward relative to the body, when horizontal it sits with a with a strong upward curve.

[image]

[image]

when horizontal, aka quadrupedal, it sits with a with a strong upward curve of the neck to bring the eyes forward. If your creature has equally long limbs this will be even stronger.

[image]

You will also notice that doing this requires a much stronger neck, which is why the neural spines of the neck vertebrae are very tall, they need a lot of space to attach muscle to hold the head in these positions. This is even more true for your creature because the head is huge, bigger even than a human. This means the neck has to sit further forward than you have drawn to have enough room, which means pushing the head even further forward or giving it a humpback.

Here look a bear head when upright.
[image]

Notice how far forward the head sits, because the neck connects to the skull right in the back of the skull like most quadrupeds, the whole head projects forward. they can pull the head further back, but only because the neck is long enough to bend in an S curve. You can see a less extreme version in this ape, which has a neck articulation in the middle between quadrupedal and upright.

[image]

You can see it in this troop of chimps:

[image]

Again notice how far forward the head is in the upright position, most of the skull is forward of the chest.
I really do recommend taking some time to study animal anatomy if you want to draw fictional animals.

Neck range of motion on humans:
[image]

Comment: What if I altered the back facing spines and/or the skull opening so it could more easily pivot back and forth between the two positions?

Comment: Or maybe make the pivot point somewhere a bit lower on the neck if the place where head and neck meet is too important to change.

Comment: @ChickenpeepChickenpeep It is not a question of pivot, the skull to neck joint (occipital-atlanto) barely moves. the whole neck flexes to change the position of the head. none of the neck vertebra have a very large range of motion, only the atlas axis joint has a decent range of motion and that is only side to side (look left or right). If you are going to be drawing fantasy creatures I can't recommend enough learning a little anatomy. here is an x-ray showing the range of motion. https://boneandspine.com/range-motion-cervical-spine/

Comment: But I asked if it were physiologically possible

Comment: Or is there any way to get the movement range I want? Besides lengthening the neck a lot?

Comment: Yes the head will have to sit much farther forward, more like the bear image I have shown, not quite that extreme but close.

Comment: do I have any other options to mess with the neck structure?

Comment: no just length or position. the flexibility of the neck is limited by many factors, you have the spine major blood vessels, and the airway, all of which cant be pinched or twisted too much.

Comment: What if more vertebrae were added? Would that give enough flex without issue?

Comment: @ChickenpeepChickenpeep yes and they would also make the neck longer.

Comment: Or maybe what would be needed if I went back to my original plan of attaching it to the back of the neck and it bending down to the shoulders like a upside down j?

Comment: @ChickenpeepChickenpeep you can do that just fine you end with something like the ape/chimp posture or the bear posture seen in my images. depending no where it articulates with the skull.

Comment: by more vertebrae added I don't mean longer. I meant the same length but broken up into more vertebrae.

Comment: @ChickenpeepChickenpeep you really can't do that, there are muscles and ligaments that attach all over the vertebra. there really is not much empty space to loose to make them smaller.

Comment: okay now I think I see it now with that monkey and bear. I'm just wanting to make sure it can get enough range. Later when I go back inside I'll try another sketch to see if I can figure things out with what you gave me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Instead of having to make the head move 90 degrees, what if just the eyes moved?

Comment: @JDługoszthat will require some creative anatomy. something like chameleon eyes maybe. A human eye for instance can only move trhough an arc of about 45 degrees.

Comment: @John I put up some quadruped positions and potential neck fixes. Could you tell me which is the best one? Suggestions? Also something I've noticed looking at reference images: cats, rabbits and rodents can position their heads in both ways, although I see these don't have the large neck spines. Are these two facts related? Do they not have the spines because they are small animals? And human necks seem to be a bit slanted forward, too. Then I've also noticed bears and tigers don't have tall neck spines. How are they different from gorilla necks? Why don't those animals need them?

Comment: chimps/gorilla need the large spines becasue they have a big brain and thus a very heavy head. ungulates with very large heads likewise need tall neck spines.   Cats..ect also have much longer necks. 1,2,8,9,10 are all fine, 3 with am more evenly distributed curve is the best quadrupedal one. Also you will note that in chimps and gorilla the skull does not sit perfectly horizontal in the quadrupedal stance but tilted down.

Comment: @John but does this creature have a long enough neck that it can look up more as quadruped?

Comment: @ChickenpeepChickenpeep only by turning its head sideways, but that is true of many animals.

Comment: @John so like cat neck can look straight forward? Also I shortened the head height a bit to decrease weight but considering how big and wide the head is shouldn't it still be enough brain space for peopley think? And I learned what the spine spikes are. Are the spinous process good for latest picture? Many thanks for hyper fixation perfectioning.

Comment: @John what is the difference between those with the spikes on the neck vs spikes on the back? What factors makes one used rather than the other?

Comment: @ChickenpeepChickenpeep the main difference is how flexible the neck is vs how strong it is. low spines gives you a weaker but flexible neck, tall spines gives you a stronger but stiffer neck. generally tall spines on the neck and back go together, but the size of the shoulders also matters. .tall spines give the muscles more leverage and allow for just more muscle but they reduce flexibility. Great apes are limited by having large heavy brains so they cannot make the neck too flexible.

Comment: @John so I'll shorten the neck ones a bit and then what if I gave it a strong nuchal ligament to compensate? I put a bump on the back of the head for good attachment point, and I'll leave the back spikes alone for the other attachment point.

Comment: A nuchal ligament means even less flexibility, really only useful in quadrupeds. you are basically stuck with long spines becasue the head has to be held upright. what you have now is fine for a biped, but for a quadruped the neck needs ot attach to the skull as a shallower (more horizontal) angle. at least half of the head should sit forward of the chest.

Comment: @John I thought you said the neck position I had was okay. What is the optimal neck spine and shoulder spine positioning for strength and flexibility for the biped/quadruped?                                       And I shortened the head height for less weight, but the general size and wideness of the head should make up for it so the brain case is still big enough for sapience?

Comment: The neck position was OK before you said you wanted it to be able to look up as a quadraped.  it should shift a little forwards if you want it to be able to look up in a quadrupedal stance.  Shortening the head does not really reduce the weight much the brain is the heavy part. widening the head makes it even less stable forcing a thicker neck.

Comment: @John the big salamander mouth is important to the design, so I'm not sure what I can change about the head. But I'm not widening it anymore than the front facing view shows. I was saying that due to the wideness, it should still have enough brain even if I shorten the head height. And by looking up I don't mean the entire snout pointing skyward, I mean I want it to be able to look straight forward; a bit higher than the gorilla does with its face pointing slightly downwards even at quadruped stance.

Comment: The space for brain is fine I am just saying you cant make the neck any more flexible. And if you want the snout to point straight ahead you will need to move the neck/skull joint, it was fine for a chimp like quadrupedal position, but you can't make a short neck flexible enough to to get it pointed all the way forward while the body rocks back and forth while running.

Comment: @John how much neck movement would it have if I gave it a longer s shaped neck? (See new image)

Comment: you will get the flexibility you want but I do suggest you make it an even curve instead of part of the neck being straight

Answer (score 4):

Head size isn't what strikes me as unfeasible here. It's how you think the spine meets the cranium.

[image]

Anatomically, the body plan and head shape / orientation you've chosen is great for a bipedal creature: when standing, its eyes face forward. The trade-off is that the base of skull rests on top of the spine like a capital on a pillar.

In order for you to keep the ability to quadripedambulate, you'd need a long saurian neck, or else bend this poor fellow's neck 90deg at the upper thorax.

Comment: I said that the spinal cord enters at the back of the head like a quadruped. It can pivot at the head so that it looks like it has a biped neck. Is that not a possible thing?

Comment: @ChickenpeepChickenpeep that neck is very wrong for a vertical skull connection.

Comment: @John what would I need to change?

Comment: @ChickenpeepChickenpeep something more like a chimp neck articulation. https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0121208

Comment: @John would that allow a quadruped head positioning too?

Comment: As chimps do both, yes it would.

Comment: @John I put a new image is that right?

Comment: @ChickenpeepChickenpeep --- I know you *said* the spinal column enters the back of the head, but that's not how you drew the creature in question! You gave her what is essentially a human alignment. If you want the spinal cord to enter the back, the neck profile will have a change a bit is all.

Comment: @elemtilas I had thought it would be okay if it had enough room to pivot to the quadruped position, but after learning that chimp neck and head connections could easily switch positions, and also gives the head more support, I decided to have that instead.

Comment: @ChickenpeepChickenpeep You have left no room for muscles on the back of the neck, I am sorry but the outward profile of your creature will be different, the head will end up slung forward of its current position. you can't get a fully upright head without an upright articulation. also consider how you want them to be quadrupedal, the more horizontal you want the back the more forward slung the head needs to be.

Comment: @ChickenpeepChickenpeep -- No worries! That's why we're all here!

Comment: @John I'm afraid I'm having a little trouble understanding then. Could you give me an image of how it would look with the chimp neck that can be both?

Comment: @elemtilas thank you I kind of need some support I get anxious trying to communicate this way without facial and voice cues, but its the best way I've found to learn very specific things that Google can't tell me. I don't often want to talk to people outside of my family even before the pandemic and I'm probably rambling too much.

Comment: @ChickenpeepChickenpeep -- Well, support & encouragement are all part of the package! Fair point about communicating, but I think you've done a fine job thus far. - Just keep doing what you're doing!

Comment: @John Ill fix tht neck thn. Wht range of movement r we looking at here? Woud I have to remove a spine spike from the sholder to hav it able of raising its head in a dog like pose? I just realized, in the beginin you said my "main problem". Is there somethin els tht needs to be fixed? Ive decided that I could stil decrease the brain size some mor and stil have as much as human, due to the overal size of the head being bigger than a human's. Tht can hlp reduce weigt. But not to much off the top or hat won't fit. This site seems to be upset that coment chain was so long. So here. U got notif now?

Answer (score 1):

While the structure is sound, if you want your creature to be able to both walk bipedally and quadipedally, you would probably need the creature's vertebrae to be individually shorter, creating more joints where it can bend its neck to be able to see properly in both stances.

Comment: Do you mean adding vertebrae without lengthening the neck? Would that cause any issue?

Comment: Chickenpeep Chickenpeep Yes, I do. The neck might not be as sturdy, due to the increased flexibility.

Comment: is there a way to make up for it?

Answer (score 0):

i believe it is width and depth wise, however intelligence tends to be proportional to head to body ratio within animals. Take this into consideration as height-wise, it may prove insufficient for more intelligent species.

Comment: The extra wideness of the brain case can't make up for it? The head is proportionally bigger than a human's, so more brain than human. So it should be able to have a little less on the top to still be enough.

Answer (score -1):

...Have you seen Erythrosuchus?

[image]

Your creature is fine.

(Wikipedia article on the Erythosuchids: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erythrosuchidae)

Comment: How wide is the head though?

Comment: ...If this diagram is correct, it's pretty narrow: http://www.reptileevolution.com/erythrosuchus.htm

Comment: That skull might have been squished in preservation, though... I will continue to look.

Comment: This art portrays the heads as a fair bit wider, although this appears to be a different species: https://sains.kompas.com/read/2019/11/25/180400923/sebelum-dinosaurus-komodo-purba-berkepala-besar-berkeliaran-di-bumi